# Variable loop inside variable loop

Tags: python, string, variables

New Python learner here. I am trying to make a program that searches for patterns of words in a string and extracts them into variables. I’m doing this by looping through lists to find particular substrings.

I have encountered a problem that has me a bit stuck and I was wondering if somebody here could help me:

I want to loop through a list of strings inside another loop of strings but I can't seem to work out where to loop through the `monthcount` variable. My code below:

```
months = ["Easter '","December"]
monthcount = 0
datecheck = [['dated ',' and inscribed '],['dated ?','verso'],['dated ','lower right'],["dated "+months[monthcount],'in']]
datedcount = 0
while datedcount <(len(datecheck)):
    if (datecheck[datedcount][0]) in inscription:
            dated = (after(inscription,(datecheck[datedcount][0])))
    if dated.isdigit() == False:
            dated = (before(dated,(datecheck[datedcount][1])))
            dated = dated.strip()
    if dated.isdigit() == True:
            dated_list[lister] = dated
    datedcount = datedcount + 1
```

Comment: It's really not clear what your code is supposed to do or what looping through `monthcount` would mean in this context. Can you explain in more detail what this code should do, and where it fails?

Comment: It looks at the inscription variable and searches for the strings in datecheck one by one. When it finds ‘dated ‘ it will then grab the substring inbetween ‘dated ‘ and ‘ and inscribed’ and then apply it to the variable dated. I want it to stop at one of the items in the datecheck list and then add to it with items from another list.

Comment: I can read the code but I can't figure out what you need to change or why.  Generally speaking, code which doesn't do what you want is not a good way of explaining what you do want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
datecheck = [['dated ',' and inscribed '],['dated ?','verso'],['dated ','lower right']]
for month in ["Easter '","December"]:
    datecheck.append(['dated {0}'.format(month), 'in'])

datedcount = 0
while datedcount < len(datecheck): ...
```

In other words, we initialize `datecheck` with the static members on your list, then append a couple of dynamically-generated ones.  Then you can loop over the final list just like before.

There is no nesting of loops here, just two sequential loops, where the first loops over the expressions we want to add.

Comment: The single quote after `Easter` is probably a bug in your code, but I didn't want to speculate too much.

Comment: No that’s to grab a single quote in the string. The full string is “dated Easter ‘97 and inscribed blabla in graphite”

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Am I at all guessing correctly what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I needed thank you! Sorry for not explaining it too well.